# How to clone Object defined by Interface

Tags: java, android

I have some different objects `Gold`, `Palladium`, `Iron` etc.these implements `Cloneable` and have a common interface named `Metal`.

In a class I receive a Metal, that could be Gold Palladium etc. and need to clone this

```
Public doSomething(Metal receivedMetal){
Metal dolly=//clone receivedMetal

dolly.doOperation();
replaceMetal(receivedMetal, dolly);
//replace use an indexOf on receivedMetal 
//and if I don't clone receivedMetal 
//doOperation edit also the original 
//receivedMetal and indexOf returns always -1
}
```

Is there a way to clone `receivedMetal` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about extending Cloneable in `Metal` and adding `clone()` to it? In below example it looks ok to me (http://rextester.com/KCUGF81783) :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

interface Metal extends Cloneable {
    public Metal clone();
}

class Iron implements Metal {

    public int val = 101;

    public Iron clone() {
        try {
            return (Iron) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {        
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    public String toString() { return "Iron " + val; }
}

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Metal metal = new Iron();
        Metal metal2 = metal.clone();

        ((Iron)metal).val = 200; // just to make sure metal2 is cloned

        System.out.println(metal2); // outputs: Iron 101
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloning can be done by creating a constructor which copies all the fields from the object given as parameter.

```
public SomeObject(SomeObject o){

   this.someField = o.getSomeField();
   //etc..

}
```

--Edit--

Instead of an interface, you could use an abstract class and define your 'clone constructor' there. In that way your subclasses can override it.

Comment: The problem is using clone on interface Metal... Metal is an interface. The clone with the various objects Gold, Palladium etc. wors, but obviously an interface cannot implements another interface and override clone()

Comment: I cannot use abstract class for various reasons